# Why Error in colSums(x, na.rm = T) : invalid 'na.rm' argument in R

Tags: r, na, reserved-words, na.rm

I try to calculate the sum of each column for my data x.
But I always got this error

```
"Error in colSums(x, na.rm = T) : invalid 'na.rm' argument"
```

Why the `na.rm` argument does not work in this case?? confused...

```
x <- cbind(x1 = 3, x2 = c(4:1, 2:5))
x[3, ] <- NA; x[4, 2] <- NA
rowSums(x)
colSums(x, na.rm=T)
```

Comment: `T` is NOT a reserved word in R.  One can (and apparently you have) overwritten its value.  Running `rm(T)` will work.  But the best approach is to stick to `TRUE` and `FALSE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to recreate your bug by overriding the usual value of `T` to be equal to `NA`:

```
> T=NA
> colSums(all,na.rm=T)
Error in colSums(all, na.rm = T) : invalid 'na.rm' argument
```

So most likely, you (or a funny co-worker?) have defined the variable `T` somewhere in your code to be equal to `NA`. To undo it, just type:

```
T=TRUE
```

or better:

```
rm(T)
```

Never forget that R doesn't really know about `T` => it is just a shorthand defined for convenience at startup, nothing more.

Comment: Doesn't need to explicitly be `NA`.  Just something that converts to `NA` via `as.logical`.  For example, `T <- 'blah'`.

Comment: I went ahead and fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

You get an error because the value of `T` has been changed to an argument which is not interpretable as logical (TRUE or FALSE), can be `NA` or a character. In my opinion is a bad habit use `T` and `F`. To avoid errors:

```
colSums(x, na.rm=TRUE)
```

`TRUE` (or `FALSE`) cannot be overwritten, as reserved words.

Just for fun, you can try:

```
T = FALSE
F = TRUE

colSums(x, na.rm=T)
colSums(x, na.rm=F)
```